# React render same element which is dynamic component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know how call this situation. It is following

I have a dynamic component which render a

`<input type="text" placeholder={this.props.reduxStateValue} />`

i.e.

```
function dynamicInput() {
    var page = this.props.kindOfPage,
        rState = this.props.reduxState;
    if (page === 'foo') {
        // foo input
        // eg. rState.value === 10
        return <input type="text" placeholder={rState.value} 
                      onChange={this.handleFoo} />
    } else {
        // bar input
        // eg. rState.value === 20
        return <input type="text" placeholder={rState.value} 
                      onChange={this.handleBar} />
    }
}
```

The above example is very simple verion. The components has many different things for each `this.props.kindOfPage`.

The problem is that when the `page === 'foo'` and I insert `100` into the `<input/>` and switch to `page !== foo`, the `100` is in the `<input/>` of `page !== foo`.

i.e.
If I call the `<input/>` of `page === 'foo'` case as `foo input` and another as `bar input`,

1. insert `100` into `foo input`
2. switch the page to `page !== foo` then `bar input` is rendered
3. the `100` is in `bar input`

But the real value of each `<input>` has its own value.
i.e.

1. The `foo input` :

value : `100`, placeholder : `10`, shown value : `100`

2. The `bar input` :

value : `''`, placeholder : `20`, shown value : `100`

What I want to do is that the `bar input` show its placeholder `20` since **we do not insert the value 100 in `bar input`**.

I think this problem is occurred because of VirtualDOM of react. The renderer just change its DOM when there is a different between each elements. Hence, whenever I change the attributes, the element is not changed and the `value` of `input` element also not changed.

But, I want to separate both and show different values. Is there any idea?

Comment: Does the `defaultValue` reset the initial value of the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I am right, I think you can simply add a key attribute to the input to fix this problem.
like this:

```
renderInput () {
        var page = this.state.kindOfPage
        var rState = this.state.reduxState;
        if (page === 'foo') {
            // foo input
            // eg. rState.value === 10
            return <input type="string" placeholder={rState.value1} key={"input1"}
                          onChange={this.handleBar} />
        } else {
            // bar input
            // eg. rState.value === 20
            console.log('test')
            return <input type="string" placeholder={rState.value} key={"input2"}
                          onChange={this.handleFoo} />
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could approach this problem slightly differently by decoupling dynamic event binding from your component's render method to deal with this characteristic of React's rendering and DOM diffing.

Rather than conditionally render components with different event handlers as you currently are, why not opt for a more efficient render implementation (ie without conditional branching) by using a common event handler that dynamically invokes the appropriate event based on your `kindOfPage` state?

So for instance, you could follow this pattern (pseudo code):

```
function handleGeneric(event) {

    var page = this.props.kindOfPage;

    // Introduce dynamic branching in "generic" event handler, like so
    switch(page) {
      case 'foo':{
        this.handleFoo(event)
        break;
      }
      default:{
        this.handleBar(event)
        break;
      }
    }
}

function dynamicInput() {
    var rState = this.props.reduxState;

    // Simplyify your render method in this way, and delegate conditional
    // branching to event handler    
    return <input type="text" placeholder={rState.value} 
                  onChange={ event => this.handleGeneric(event) } />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and I understand your way. But there is a issue I do not mention. The returned component is actually complecated and the input is very differenct each other. Just the position of those `input` are same accidentally. But I will try this way.

Comment: Hi @wallah ok, let me know if I can help you out in anyway

Comment: What I am trying to do is the `placeholer` and `value` of `input`. Since the value is holding position, the placeholder and another value of page show wrong data.